# Error opening database, Cordova Web Browser

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a database for an application in ionic 2, and it fails where I create it:

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'details.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    //... }
```

**Error:**

```
OPEN database: details.db  
Error: exec proxy not found for :: SQLitePlugin :: close
Error: exec proxy not found for :: SQLitePlugin :: open
OPEN database: details.db FAILED, aborting any pending transactions
Error: Could not open database
    at newSQLError (SQLitePlugin.js:25)
    at SQLitePlugin.js:198
    at Object.module.exports [as exec] (cordova.js:1006)
    at SQLitePlugin.js:207
    at Object.module.exports [as exec] (cordova.js:1006)
    at SQLitePlugin.open (SQLitePlugin.js:210)
    at new SQLitePlugin (SQLitePlugin.js:84)
    at Object.<anonymous> (SQLitePlugin.js:600)
    at Object.openDatabase (SQLitePlugin.js:58)
    at index.js:176
```

I have added the Cordova functionalities via `ionic cordova platform add browser`.

I run the app liko so:

`ionic cordova run browser`

**Does it mean that this cordova functionality(create database) is not available in a browser?**

Comment: a browser is not a mobile device. for example, when in need to test things depending on plugins, i tend to check if we are in a real device or running on a browser. the nearest thing to sql that you will have on browser is websql, however it is deprecated: https://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot open database via Cordova Web Browser. 
What you can do is use the [Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) provided by Visual Studio.

This way the database will be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you'll have to use a mock to be able to use browser environment with SQlite. I will try this, too: https://medium.com/@tintin301/ionic-sqlite-storage-setting-up-for-browser-development-and-testing-67c0f17fc7af

Some people warned about this so I would recommend this other approach: 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-sqlite-issue/87416/18